# XPath with MSXML, "scope" of XPath-expressions

Tags: xpath, msxml, paradox

i have an understanding-problem using Microsoft XML Core Services 6.0 (MSXML) with XPath-expressions.
I´ve broken down the problem to the most simple case. So let´s take the following XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element name="E1A1">
        <subEle value="1a"/>
        <subEle value="1b"/>
        <subEle value="1c"/>
    </element>

    <element name="E2A1">
        <subEle value="2a"/>
        <subEle value="2b"/>
        <subEle value="3b"/>
    </element>

    <element name="E3A1">
        <subEle value="3a"/>
        <subEle value="3b"/>
        <subEle value="3c"/>
    </element>
</root>
```

I want to get the "`value`"-attribues per "element". I will use pseudo-code to describe
my problem and i will focus on the important things, so i will not write how i initialize 
the Msxml2.DOMDocument variable etc. .
First, i get all "`element`"-nodes that have a `name`-attribute:

```
oNodeList = oDom.selectNodes("//element[@name]")
```

The result of the selectNodes-statement is a nodelist, where i access the items node by node
in a for-loop. In this loop, i execute another selectNodes-statement, that gives me (at least i thought so) 
the "`subEle`"s for each "`element`":

```
for i from 1 to oNodeList.length
    oNodeMain = oNodeList.nextNode()    
    oNodeResList = oNodeMain.selectNodes("//subEle")
    msgInfo("n items", oNodeResList.length)
endFor
```

And here comes the problem: the selectNodes-statement in the loops seems to have *ALL* "subEle"s
in scope; the messagebox pops up three times, telling me the length of the nodelist is 9. 
I would have expected that it pops up 3 times, telling me each time that the nodelist has a length of 3 (because
every "`element`" has exactly 3 "`subEle`"s), since i´m doing the selectNodes-statement on "`oNodeMain`",
which gets the nextNode in each loop. Maybe i just need to modify XPath-expression in the loop and
don´t use the "`//`", because it works then, but i have no idea why.

The program i use for this is Paradox 11 and i use MSXML by OLE. 
Is this behaviour "normal", where is my misunderstanding? Any suggestions on how to achieve what i´m 
trying are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use an absolute path starting with `/`, instead use a relative path i.e. `oNodeMain.selectNodes("subEle")` selects all `subEle` child elements of `oNodeMain` and `oNodeMain.selectNodes(".//subEle")` selects all descendant `subEle` elements of `oNodeMain`.

Your path starting with `//` searches from the root node (also called document node).

Comment: Thank you, i know that using "//" will search the whole node, but i just don´t understand why it has every node in scope, since oNodeMain is just one node from the nodelist. :-(

Comment: The reason is that `oNodeMain` is still part of the document as a whole, and XPaths starting with `/` traverse the document starting at the root.

Comment: If you do `oNodeMain.selectNodes("/")` you select the root node or document node `oNodeMain` is contained in (i.e. the same node as in your `oDom` variable). And any path starting with `/` selects down from that root node. So basically XPath allows you to navigate around in the complete document and that does not change just because you are working with a particular node collected in a node list. For your `selectNodes` inside the `for` loop you need to use a relative path as shown (`selectNodes("subEle")` for child elements or `selectNodes("descendant::subEle")` or `selectNodes(".//subEle")`).

Comment: @whocares81 If Martin's answer solved your issue, please mark his answer as correct by clicking the checkmark icon.