# Selecting an xml node from it's tag attribute rather than "tagname" using VBA

Tags: xml, vba

Sample XML:

```
<DATA>   
<DIMENSION Name="NST1">
    <MEMBERS>
        <MEMBER>
            <LABEL>[None]</LABEL>
            <AT Name="IsCalculated">N</AT>
            <AT Name="SwitchSignForFlow">N</AT>
            <AT Name="SwitchTypeForFlow">N</AT>
        </MEMBER>
        <MEMBER>
            <LABEL>TotalNST1</LABEL>
            <AT Name="IsCalculated">N</AT>
            <AT Name="SwitchSignForFlow">N</AT>
            <AT Name="SwitchTypeForFlow">N</AT>
        </MEMBER>
    </MEMBERS>
</DIMENSION>
<DIMENSION Name="NST2">
    <MEMBERS>
        <MEMBER>
            <LABEL>[None]</LABEL>
            <AT Name="IsCalculated">N</AT>
            <AT Name="SwitchSignForFlow">N</AT>
            <AT Name="SwitchTypeForFlow">N</AT>
        </MEMBER>
        <MEMBER>
            <LABEL>TotalNST1</LABEL>
            <AT Name="IsCalculated">N</AT>
            <AT Name="SwitchSignForFlow">N</AT>
            <AT Name="SwitchTypeForFlow">N</AT>
        </MEMBER>
    </MEMBERS>
</DIMENSION>
 |
 |    MANY MANY MORE DIMENSIONS HERE
 |
</DATA>
```

Using the above xml file i am trying to use VBA to create a dictionary with a number of keys which correspond to the name attributes of each DIMENSION node and all the elements contained with in concatenated as the entry associated with that key.

```
 IE:
 Key:     Data:
 NST1:    NST1; [None]; N; N; N;  
 NST2:    NST2; [None]; N; N; N;
```

It is simple enough to use getElementsByTagName(DIMENSION) however my problem is that as you can see the XML file contains many dimensions with the same layout and tag name "DIMENSION" only distinguished by attribute Name in the Dimension tag.

Is there a way to select the dimension by its "name attribute" ie NST1, NST2 etc rather than it's tag name?

I have the code required to create these dictionary entries once my VBA script is "looking at the correct dimension" my issue is to "look at" a dimension by its attribute?

Any thoughts or ideas would be gratefully received.

Many thanks

Comment: See this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728102/xpath-with-msxml-scope-of-xpath-expressions. More specifically, the code snippet that follows "First, i get all "element"-nodes that have a name-attribute: "

Comment: Thanks for this link, it got me most of the way their, I think i just needed to brush up on how xpath is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just use XPath like in the below example:

```vb
Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
objXMLDoc.async = False
objXMLDoc.load "C:\Sample.xml"
objXMLDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
' set target value of the Name attribute NST2
strTargetName = "NST2"
' the resulting node list contains all DIMENSION nodes having NST2 as Name
Set objNodeList = objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("//DIMENSION[@Name='" & strTargetName & "']")
' show the content of the first NST2 node from collection
MsgBox objNodeList(0).xml
```

I saved your XML snippet into C:\Sample.xml, the output is as follows:

```xml
<DIMENSION Name="NST2">
    <MEMBERS>
        <MEMBER>
            <LABEL>[None]</LABEL>
            <AT Name="IsCalculated">N</AT>
            <AT Name="SwitchSignForFlow">N</AT>
            <AT Name="SwitchTypeForFlow">N</AT>
        </MEMBER>
        <MEMBER>
            <LABEL>TotalNST1</LABEL>
            <AT Name="IsCalculated">N</AT>
            <AT Name="SwitchSignForFlow">N</AT>
            <AT Name="SwitchTypeForFlow">N</AT>
        </MEMBER>
    </MEMBERS>
</DIMENSION>
```

Comment: Thank you between this and the comment above I got there, the problem was mostly my lack of understanding of Xpath.... The more you know